# Иконки в v-select vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Как можно добавить выбор иконок в селект vuetify? Как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е есть селект,

```
             <v-select
             :items=""
             label="">
             </v-select>
```

и есть иконки

```
<v-icon>person<v-icon>
<v-icon>folder<v-icon>
<v-icon>create<v-icon>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `scoped slot` для своих целей 
Для v-select есть два scoped slot:

- selection: описывает, как v-select должен отображать элементы при выборе
- item: описывает, как v-select должен отображать элементы при открытии

Ваш код:

```
<v-select :items="list">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
        <v-icon color="#000000">{{ data.item.icon }}</v-icon>
    </template>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        <v-icon color="#000000">{{ data.item.icon }}</v-icon>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

И в data указываете ваш список иконок

```
list: [
    { icon: 'home' },
    ...
]
```

Подробнее можете посмотреть на [официальном сайте](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#api)