# Vuetify select option/value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Помогите разобраться с селектом во Vuetify:

```
<v-select
v-model="genere"
:items="generes"
:dense="true"
label="Жанр"
></v-select>
```

:items связан с массивом generes = ['боевик', 'триллер', 'комедия'] и выступает аналогом option
Мне необходимо к каждому жанру привязать свой value, как это делается в обычном селекте, чтобы при отправке формы получать именно value, которое будет соответствовать выбранной опции. Не совсем пойму как это сделать. В документации указано, что item-value также может быть массивом, но ничего не получается

Answer (score 1):

Нужно лишь забиндить item-value на нужное поле из объекта **`genere`**. Важный аспект здесь что нужно биндить текстовое название поля. Такое же можно и c текстом соответствующим значению провернуть.

```
       <v-select :items="generes" v-model="genere" item-value="id" item-text="name" return-object label="Жанр"></select>
```

Еще больше свободы можно получить если воспользоваться фичей slot-scope.

```
    <v-select :items="generes" label="Жанр" outline v-model="genere">
      <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
        {{ data.item.name }}
      </template>
      <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        {{ data.item.id + ')' + data.item.name }}
      </template>
    </v-select>
```

---

Вот еще пример от другого [пользователя RUSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936486)